# Cannot write to /proc/1/fd/1 from Docker

Tags: php, docker, apache2

After a lot of researching, appearantly when you run Apache as main process for Docker, then  docker logs follows /proc/**1**/fd/1 instead of /proc/**self**/fd/1.

**Problem:**

I am using apache2 as web server and unfortunately apache's www-data user cannot write to /proc/1/fd/1

Code for testing:

```
$handle = fopen('/proc/1/fd/1', 'a');
fwrite($handle, 'abc');
fclose($handle);
```

This gives me output of: **fopen(/proc/1/fd/1): Failed to open stream: Permission denied**

**Goal:**

Having possibility to write to output that Docker logs can follow while having possibility to write persistent volume as well (not exactly part of this topic, but maybe useful).

**Extra info:**

- even though logs go to persistent volume as well, tailing these files is unpreferred option.
- research said that editing permissions of /proc/xxx/xxx folders is unwise and also quick proof of concept said that is easily not doable.
- related to: [PHP in Docker - fopen() or file_put_contents() cannot write to /proc/1/fd/2 for stdout writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55619229/php-in-docker-fopen-or-file-put-contents-cannot-write-to-proc-1-fd-2-for)

Comment: I assume you're using PHP? Can't you use `console.log`?

Comment: I am using PHP, thanks for pointing out - added extra tag.

Regarding console.log - PHP equivalent is error_log. For simplicity of my example I added handler as www-data has problems, not my main process which is ran as root.

If I put ErrorLog "/proc/1/fd/1" into my VirtualHost config, then I successfully can get my data Docker logs, but this solves only half my problem.

Main problem is that I need to have logs to persistent storage as well and not only to ones marked in VirtualHost config.

Comment: Why isn't Apache process ID 1?  What image are you running, and how are you modifying its startup sequence?

Comment: @DavidMaze Apache process ID is 1. Using php:8.0.23-apache image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to write to the log of the container, you can use `error_log`.

Create an `index.php` file containing

```
<?php
error_log("abc");
echo "Hello from PHP";
?>
```

and run a container using something like

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v $(pwd):/var/www/html php:8.0-apache
```

Then, when you go to `localhost:8080`, you will get something like

```
[Tue Jan 03 08:43:28.255070 2023] [php:notice] [pid 17] [client 172.17.0.1:54326] abc
```

in the container log.

Comment: This isn't that much about using error_log function rather than having PHP able to write to /proc/1/fd/1

I have no problem logging to proc with Apache & PHP when ErrorLog value is /proc/1/fd/1.